# DSO missing from command line when use concurrent_queue of TBB

Tags: c++11, qt-creator

I'm trying to use TBB to video proces in the Qt project. But running the project it gives me some errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3tbb8internal24concurrent_queue_base_v3D2Ev'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

When I searched for the error it says to .pro file edit adding: LIBS =-lpthread

but it is already there.

How do I should to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was resolved by add LIBS+=-ltbb to .pro file.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue.......
and I use eclipse to write my c++ programs......

and i resolved my issue by adding a new entry 'tbb' under the eclipse c++ poject properties -> c/c++ Bild -> settings -> GCC c++ Linker -> Libraries -> Librarie(-l) section

Ans the same thing is shown in the following figure [Added tbb in project property settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IunJ.png)